# Displaying the Taxonomy and a Queried Term on a taxonomy.php page?

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, terms

I'm using a WP plugin Called [Search and Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/) to filter a custom post type — a user directory.

The plugin lets a user filter the directory by specifying terms.

It will also let a user filter the directoy by MULTIPLE terms.

When it does so, I get a slug constructed like this:

http://www.consular-corps-college.org/dir-type/chiefs-of-protocol/?country=united-states-of-america

Posts are returned via the `taxonomy.php` page.

First, I didn't even know you could do this, so that's cool.

But my question is, how do I display the second term in the slug query?

In other words, I can get the taxonomy.php page to display the term "Chiefs of Protocol" with `single_term_title()`.

But how can I get WordPress to display the second term which is queried in the slug — in this case "United States of America"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the value of querystring

```
$country = $_GET['country'];
```

Comment: That certainly does return the querystring — but how can I get the friendly name of that term? IE, this returns "united-states-of-america", which is the slug for that term.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the slug of the term in the query string, so you can use the [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) function to get the term object. For example, assuming your taxonomy name is 'dir-type':

```
$country = get_term_by( 'slug', $_GET['country'], 'dir-type' );
```

Using that, you can then print out information from the term object like this:

```
echo $country->name; // print the name
print_r( $country ); // print all available properties (for debugging purposes)
```

The first line there will show the name; the second will show you the rest of the information stored in the term object (just for your interest!)

Comment: Well, that looked great but I can only get the slug to return. After running get_term_by, everything else fails.

Comment: @Tomasch Oops, I forgot to include the taxonomy parameter - it's required (in all cases but one, and certainly in this case). Assuming your taxonomy is called `'dir-type'`, try that updated code now.

Comment: @Tomasch Also, if it fails again, please explain what's happening - i.e. error messages, etc. 'Everything else fails' isn't a helpful error description. If you aren't getting errors when something goes wrong, make sure [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) is turned on.

Comment: Well, that just opens another can of works. It looks like we might have an error in Custom Post Type UI — the plugin I'm using for custom post types. I get this error, abbreviated:

`
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/c/t/s/ctsgraphics/html/_ccc/wp-content/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/custom-post-type-ui.php:471) in /home/content/c/t/s/ctsgraphics/html/_ccc/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1167`

Comment: @Tomasch Hmm I can't really help with that, as I don't know the plugin. You could see if there are any updates available for it, contact the author, or drop it and create the post types yourself using register_post_type(). Alternatively, the error _might_ not be a fatal one and you might be able to still use it fine.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate it. But looks like there's something there creating the error.

I'll look into some other options re the plug in and check your code again!